# Global instance of class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Im trying to make an instance of a class available in all methods in the .m file. Instead of doing this inside every method:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    Class *c = [Class new];
}
```

My attempt in the .h file:

```
@interface RandomViewController : UIViewController
{
    Class *c [Class new];
}
```

But It does'nt work, I get error

> Expected ';' at end of declaration list

How would I make this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Normally you'd do this in the init routine.  But you still must have a declaration in the .h.

Comment: You know that `Class` is a type in Objective-C, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an instance variable, and set it up in your designated initializer. Here's a sample `@implementation` block.

```
@implementation RandomViewController {
    // Instance variable names should start with an underscore, by convention.
    Class *_c;
}

...

// Designated initializer for UIViewController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        _c = [[Class alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

...

- (void)someMethodThatNeedsAClassInstance
{
    [_c doSomething];
}
```

If you're not using ARC, you'll need to add `[_c release]` to your `dealloc` implementation.

Now, in every method in your class, you may refer to `_c` and get the instance you created in the initializer. As a side note, this isn't really a 'global' instance - it is per-object. Each individual view controller you create will have its own instance of `_c`. Also, an even better approach is to declare a [property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) and not bother declaring an instance variable at all.

Comment: Why would it be better to do it in the initializer method rather than like the other answers where it is put in the viewDidLoad method?
Also, what do you mean by declaring a property instead?
Like '@property (nonatomic, strong) Class *_c;'
Would this work better?

Comment: ViewDidLoad can be called several times during the view controller's lifetime, so this avoids unnecessary re-allocation. On older versions of iOS and pre-ARC it was more important to reduce duplicated cleanup in dealloc and viewDidUnload.

Comment: And about the making a property of the class? Thanks for all the response :)

Comment: Having a property is cleaner code IMO as well as be making all changes to ivar go through accessors there are some benefits, pre-ARC it was more important but if you need to emit a KVO notification manually some time in the future or have changes to ivars have some additional side effect then if you used the property always you won't have much code to change.

Answer (score 0):

In .h file:

```
@interface RandomViewController : UIViewController
{
    Class *c;
}
```

In .m file:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    c = [[Class alloc] init];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what do it do the class method? if return void:

Class.h file:

```
@interface Class: NSObject
{
}
- (void)new;
```

RandomViewController.h

```
@interface RandomViewController : UIViewController
    {
        Class *c;
    }
```

RandomViewController.m file

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    c = [[Class alloc] init];  
    //call the method
    [c new];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right - you wouldn't declare `new` in the view controller's header but in `Class`'s header.

Comment: Also, 'new' is, from what I know, another way of making an instance of a class. Alike [[Class alloc] init];